# WxWidgets with Visual Studio and Unicode Sources

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf-8, wxwidgets

Following the [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) manifesto, and mostly its part: [how to do text on Windows](http://utf8everywhere.org/#how), I've created this simple example with wxWidgets. I wanted wxWidgets to interpret string literals as UTF-8 strings, but it seems, that library gets me wrong.

single source file - `main.cpp`, encoded as `UTF-8 without signature` (in msvc terminology):

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class Mainw: public wxFrame
{
public:
   Mainw(wxWindow * parent, wxWindowID wxId, const wxString & label)
      : wxFrame(parent, wxId, label)
   {
      wxBoxSizer * sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
      sizer->Add(new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Кириллица")), 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);
      this->SetSizer(sizer);
   }
};


class MyApp: public wxApp
{
public:
   bool OnInit()
   {
      Mainw *f = new Mainw(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("Frame"));
      f->Show();
      return true;
   }
};


IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

Preprocessor Definitions:

```
UNICODE
_UNICODE
WIN32
__WXMSW__
_WINDOWS
_DEBUG
__WXDEBUG__
wxUSE_UNICODE=1
WXUSINGDLL=1
```

Linked with WxWidgets Library version 3.0.2

Headers - http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.2/wxWidgets-3.0.2_headers.7z/download

Binaries - http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.2/binaries/wxMSW-3.0.2_vc90_Dev.7z/download

Being run, this example produces window with text `РљРёСЂРёР»Р»РёС†Р°`, instead of `Кириллица` (there was something similar, but it changed to this, when I tried to select it to copy here). It means, that wxWidgets fails to interpret my string literal as UTF-8, but interprets it as something else - maybe as text in system encoding which is `windows-1251`.

Is there any way to change this behavior of library to match utf-8 everywhere manifesto?

#### Conclusion:

I gave up. I managed to build library with msvc and flag `wxUSE_UNICODE_UTF8` but it would not help without some complex changes in library configuration headers. It seems, that this option is POSIX only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to change this behavior of library to match utf-8 everywhere manifesto?

No, not under Windows because Windows doesn't support UTF-8 locales (in principle, they could be emulated by the CRT, but AFAIK no compiler does it) and `wxString(const char*)` ctor interprets the string in the current locale encoding by default.

There are two simple solutions however:

1. Use `wxString::FromUTF8()` explicitly.
2. Use `wxString(const wchar_t*)` ctor with `L"..."` wide char argument.

Just for completeness, you also might force the library into accepting UTF-8 narrow text by rebuilding it with `wxUSE_UTF8_LOCALE_ONLY=1`, but I'm far from sure if this is going to work because the CRT locale will still be different and so using non-ASCII characters with any CRT functions will most likely not work as expected, so I definitely do *not* recommend doing this unless you're just curious to see what happens.

Comment: it seems, that this is possible, though not recommended because of performance: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/Tr7QmSeuF9s But I don't know where I can set flag wxUSE_UNICODE_UTF8 to build with it library with msvc. CRT alsa handle utf-8 strings just fins, AFAIK, only WINAPI may have problems with it, but wx can handle it

Comment: Also, `wxUSE_UTF8_LOCALE_ONLY=1` does not work - wxWidgets has a fool-safe mechanism to prevent this option to be used with library, compiled with a `wxUSE_UNICODE_WCHAR` option

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that `wxUSE_UTF8_LOCALE_ONLY` requires `wxUSE_UNICODE_UTF8`, so you need to set both of them to true and, of course, you need to rebuild the library. As for CRT dealing with UTF-8 just fine, are you really sure about this?

Comment: Well, It was a hasty statement :)